# Bose QuietComfort 35 stopped connecting to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, bose

I have a Bose QuietComfort 35 and it used to able to use it on my Windows 10 PC over an aplic bluetooth dongle.

Unfortunately, it stopped working. It's not possible anymore to switch from my speakers to the be headphones. The device still shows up in the list of devices and gets listed as *paired* but when I click on connect it shows *connecting* for a moment only to go back to *paired* afterwards.

Resetting the device list by holding the button, works but afterwards I still can't successfully connect the headphones.

The headphones still connect correctly to my Pixel 3 XL.